# Convert dynamic XML to html using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML input which is obtained dynamically.How can i write the style sheet for it.I wanna show the xml in a tree format(using ul & li).I didn't get a clear idea to achieve it.
This is my xml format.Please give me a idea to start with it.

```
<body>
<elements segmentid="0" segmentuid="_020" description="Beginning of Hierarchical Transaction" required="true" empty="false">
  <datas required="true" name="Hierarchical Structure Code" text="0022">0022</datas>
  <datas required="true" name="Transaction Set Purpose Code" usertext="13">13</datas>
  <datas required="false" name="Reference Identification">199</datas>
  <datas required="false" name="Date" format="CCYYMMDD" function="Date">20111219</datas>
  <datas required="false" name="Time" format="HHMMSS" function="Time">010720</datas>
  <datas required="false" name="Transaction Type Code" />
</elements>
<elements segmentid="1" segmentuid="2000A_010" description="Information Source Level" required="true" havechildren="True" empty="false">
  <elements segmentid="2" segmentuid="2100A_030" description="Information Source Name" required="true" empty="false" customid="1298">
    <datas required="true" name="Entity Identifier Code" usertext="PR">PR</datas>
    <datas required="true" name="Entity Type Qualifier" usertext="2">2</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name Last or Organization Name">UNITED</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name First" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Middle" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Prefix" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Suffix" />
    <datas required="false" name="Identification Code Qualifier" usertext="PI">PI</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Identification Code" />
    <datas required="false" name="Entity Relationship Code" />
    <datas required="false" name="Entity Identifier Code" />
  </elements>
</elements>
<elements segmentid="3" segmentuid="2000B_010" description="Information Receiver Level" required="true" havechildren="True" empty="false">
  <elements segmentid="4" segmentuid="2100B_030" description="Information Receiver Name" required="true" empty="false">
    <datas required="true" name="Entity Identifier Code" usertext="FA">FA</datas>
    <datas required="true" name="Entity Type Qualifier" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Last or Organization Name">SWXRAY</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name First" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Middle" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Prefix" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Suffix" usertext="" />
    <datas required="false" name="Identification Code Qualifier" usertext="FI">XX</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Identification Code" usertext="760022799">1467524231</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Entity Relationship Code" />
    <datas required="false" name="Entity Identifier Code" />
    <elements segmentid="5" segmentuid="2100B_040" description="Information Receiver Additional Identification" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification Qualifier" />
      <datas required="false" name="Reference Identification" />
      <datas required="false" name="Description" />
      <datas required="false" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFIER" />
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="6" segmentuid="2100B_060" description="Information Receiver Address" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="true" name="Address Information" />
      <datas required="false" name="Address Information" />
    </elements>  
</elements>
<elements segmentid="10" segmentuid="2000C_010" description="Subscriber Level" required="true" havechildren="false" empty="false">
  <elements segmentid="11" segmentuid="2000C_020" description="Subscriber Trace Number" required="false" empty="true">
    <datas required="true" name="Trace Type Code" text="1">1</datas>
    <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification">199</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Originating Company Identifier" text="9EMDEDI" usertext="9EMDEDI">9EMDEDI</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Reference Identification" />
  </elements>
  <elements segmentid="12" segmentuid="2100C_030" description="Subscriber Name" required="true" empty="false">
    <datas required="true" name="Entity Identifier Code" text="IL">IL</datas>
    <datas required="true" name="Entity Type Qualifier" text="1" usertext="1">1</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name Last or Organization Name">dfgdfg</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name First">dfgdfgdf</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name Middle" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Prefix" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Suffix" />
    <datas required="false" name="Identification Code Qualifier" usertext="MI">MI</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Identification Code">54645654</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Entity Relationship Code" />
    <datas required="false" name="Entity Identifier Code" />
    <elements segmentid="13" segmentuid="2100C_040" description="Subscriber Additional Identification" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification Qualifier" />
      <datas required="false" name="Reference Identification" />
      <datas required="false" name="Description" />
      <datas required="false" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFIER" />
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="14" segmentuid="2100C_060" description="Subscriber Address" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="true" name="Address Information" />
      <datas required="false" name="Address Information" />
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="15" segmentuid="2100C_070" description="Subscriber City/State/ZIP Code" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="false" name="City Name" />
      <datas required="false" name="State or Province Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Postal Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Country Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Location Qualifier" />
      <datas required="false" name="Location Identifier" />
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="16" segmentuid="2100C_090" description="Provider Information" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="true" name="Provider Code" />
      <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification Qualifier" text="ZZ">ZZ</datas>
      <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification" />
      <datas required="false" name="State or Province Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="PROVIDER SPECIALTY INFORMATION" />
      <datas required="false" name="Provider Organization Code" />
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="17" segmentuid="2100C_100" description="Subscriber Demographic Information" required="false" empty="false">
      <datas required="false" name="Date Time Period Format Qualifier" text="D8">D8</datas>
      <datas required="false" name="Date Time Period" format="CCYYMMDD" function="Date">19761010</datas>
      <datas required="false" name="Gender Code" usertext="" />
      <datas required="false" name="Marital Status Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Race or Ethnicity Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Citizenship Status Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Country Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Basis of Verification Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Quantity" />
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="18" segmentuid="2100C_110" description="Subscriber Relationship" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="true" name="Yes/No Condition or Response Code" text="Y">Y</datas>
      <datas required="true" name="Individual Relationship Code" text="18">18</datas>
      <datas required="false" name="Maintenance Type Code" text="001">001</datas>
      <datas required="false" name="Maintenance Reason Code" text="25">25</datas>
      <datas required="false" name="Benefit Status Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Medicare Plan Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Consolidated Omnibus Budget Reconciliation Act (COBRA) Qualifying" />
      <datas required="false" name="Employment Status Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Student Status Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Yes/No Condition or Response Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Date Time Period Format Qualifier" />
      <datas required="false" name="Date Time Period" />
      <datas required="false" name="Confidentiality Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="City Name" />
      <datas required="false" name="State or Province Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Country Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Number" />
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="19" segmentuid="2100C_120" description="Subscriber Date" required="false" empty="false">
      <datas required="true" name="Date/Time Qualifier" usertext="307">307</datas>
      <datas required="true" name="Date Time Period Format Qualifier" usertext="D8">D8</datas>
      <datas required="true" name="Date Time Period" format="CCYYMMDD" function="Date">20111219</datas>
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="20" segmentuid="2110C_130" description="Subscriber Eligibility or Benefit Inquiry Information" required="false" empty="false" repeat="10">
      <datas required="false" name="Service Type Code">4</datas>
      <datas required="false" name="COMPOSITE MEDICAL PROCEDURE IDENTIFIER">
        <compositedatas required="true" name="Product/Service ID Qualifier" />
        <compositedatas required="true" name="Product/Service ID" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Procedure Modifier" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Procedure Modifier" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Procedure Modifier" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Procedure Modifier" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Description" />
      </datas>
      <datas required="false" name="Coverage Level Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Insurance Type Code" />
      <elements segmentid="21" segmentuid="2110C_135" description="Subscriber Spend Down Amount" required="false" empty="true">
        <datas required="true" name="Amount Qualifier Code" text="R">R</datas>
        <datas required="true" name="Monetary Amount" />
        <datas required="false" name="Credit/Debit Flag Code" />
      </elements>
      <elements segmentid="22" segmentuid="2110C_170" description="Subscriber Eligibility or Benefit Additional Inquiry Information" required="false" empty="true">
        <datas required="false" name="Code List Qualifier Code" />
        <datas required="false" name="Industry Code" />
        <datas required="false" name="Code Category" />
        <datas required="false" name="Free-Form Message Text" />
        <datas required="false" name="Quantity" />
        <datas required="false" name="COMPOSITE UNIT OF MEASURE" />
        <datas required="false" name="Surface/Layer/Position Code" />
        <datas required="false" name="Surface/Layer/Position Code" />
        <datas required="false" name="Surface/Layer/Position Code" />
      </elements>
      <elements segmentid="23" segmentuid="2110C_190" description="Subscriber Additional Information" required="false" empty="true">
        <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification Qualifier" />
        <datas required="false" name="Reference Identification" />
        <datas required="false" name="Description" />
        <datas required="false" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFIER" />
      </elements>
      <elements segmentid="24" segmentuid="2110C_200" description="Subscriber Eligibility/Benefit Date" required="false" empty="true">
        <datas required="true" name="Date/Time Qualifier" />
        <datas required="true" name="Date Time Period Format Qualifier" />
        <datas required="true" name="Date Time Period" format="CCYYMMDD(or)CCYYMMDD-CCYYMMDD" />
      </elements>
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="20" segmentuid="2110C_130" description="Subscriber Eligibility or Benefit Inquiry Information" required="false" empty="false" repeat="10">
      <datas required="false" name="Service Type Code">30</datas>
      <datas required="false" name="COMPOSITE MEDICAL PROCEDURE IDENTIFIER">
        <compositedatas required="true" name="Product/Service ID Qualifier" />
        <compositedatas required="true" name="Product/Service ID" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Procedure Modifier" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Procedure Modifier" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Procedure Modifier" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Procedure Modifier" />
        <compositedatas required="false" name="Description" />
      </datas>
      <datas required="false" name="Coverage Level Code" />
      <datas required="false" name="Insurance Type Code" />
      <elements segmentid="21" segmentuid="2110C_135" description="Subscriber Spend Down Amount" required="false" empty="true">
        <datas required="true" name="Amount Qualifier Code" text="R">R</datas>
        <datas required="true" name="Monetary Amount" />
        <datas required="false" name="Credit/Debit Flag Code" />
      </elements>
      <elements segmentid="22" segmentuid="2110C_170" description="Subscriber Eligibility or Benefit Additional Inquiry Information" required="false" empty="true">
        <datas required="false" name="Code List Qualifier Code" />
        <datas required="false" name="Industry Code" />
        <datas required="false" name="Code Category" />
        <datas required="false" name="Free-Form Message Text" />
        <datas required="false" name="Quantity" />
        <datas required="false" name="COMPOSITE UNIT OF MEASURE" />
        <datas required="false" name="Surface/Layer/Position Code" />
        <datas required="false" name="Surface/Layer/Position Code" />
        <datas required="false" name="Surface/Layer/Position Code" />
      </elements>
      <elements segmentid="23" segmentuid="2110C_190" description="Subscriber Additional Information" required="false" empty="true">
        <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification Qualifier" />
        <datas required="false" name="Reference Identification" />
        <datas required="false" name="Description" />
        <datas required="false" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFIER" />
      </elements>
      <elements segmentid="24" segmentuid="2110C_200" description="Subscriber Eligibility/Benefit Date" required="false" empty="true">
        <datas required="true" name="Date/Time Qualifier" />
        <datas required="true" name="Date Time Period Format Qualifier" />
        <datas required="true" name="Date Time Period" format="CCYYMMDD(or)CCYYMMDD-CCYYMMDD" />
      </elements>
    </elements>
  </elements>
</elements>
<elements segmentid="25" segmentuid="2000D_010" description="Dependent Level" required="false" havechildren="False" empty="true">
  <elements segmentid="26" segmentuid="2000D_020" description="Dependent Trace Number" required="false" empty="true">
    <datas required="true" name="Trace Type Code" text="1">1</datas>
    <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification">199</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Originating Company Identifier" text="9EMDEDI" usertext="9EMDEDI">9EMDEDI</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Reference Identification" />
  </elements>
  <elements segmentid="27" segmentuid="2100D_030" description="Dependent Name" required="true" empty="false">
    <datas required="true" name="Entity Identifier Code" text="03">03</datas>
    <datas required="true" name="Entity Type Qualifier" text="1">1</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name Last or Organization Name">dfgdfg</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name First">dfgdfgdf</datas>
    <datas required="false" name="Name Middle" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Prefix" />
    <datas required="false" name="Name Suffix" />
    <datas required="false" name="Identification Code Qualifier" />
    <datas required="false" name="Identification Code" />
    <datas required="false" name="Entity Relationship Code" />
    <datas required="false" name="Entity Identifier Code" />
    <elements segmentid="28" segmentuid="2100D_040" description="Dependent Additional Identification" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="true" name="Reference Identification Qualifier" />
      <datas required="false" name="Reference Identification" />
      <datas required="false" name="Description" />
      <datas required="false" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFIER" />
    </elements>
    <elements segmentid="29" segmentuid="2100D_060" description="Dependent Address" required="false" empty="true">
      <datas required="true" name="Address Information" />
      <datas required="false" name="Address Information" />
    </elements>
 </elements>
```

My Desired out should be

```
<ul>1.Beginning of Hierarchical Transaction
           <li>Hierarchical Structure Code-0022</li>
           <li>Transaction Set Purpose Code-13</li>
           <li>Reference Identification-199</li>
           <li>Date-20111219</li>
           <li>Time-010720</li>
</ul>    
<ul>2.Information Source Level
<ul>a.Information Source Name
           <li>Entity Identifier Code-PR</li>
           <li>Entity Type Qualifier-2</li>
           <li>Name Last or Organization Name-UNITED</li>
           <li>Name First-""</li>
           <li>Name Middle-""</li>
```

Like this.

Comment: Please show us how your desired html output should look - it's hard to tell the actual tree structure in `<ul>` from your description.

Comment: Formatted output is shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Filiburt said, it's not perfectly clear how you want to organise your ouput, but at the sametime you state that you only need some help to get you on the way so here is a solution draft to work with:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/body/elements[@segmentid='0']">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="/body/elements[@segmentid=0]/datas[@name='Hierarchical Structure Code']/@name"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/body/elements[@segmentid=0]/datas[@name='Hierarchical Structure Code']"/></li>
         <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="/body/elements[@segmentid=0]/datas[@name='Transaction Set Purpose Code']/@name"/>
         <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/body/elements[@segmentid=0]/datas[@name='Transaction Set Purpose Code']"/></li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/body/elements/elements">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="./datas[@name='Entity Identifier Code']/@name"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./datas[@name='Entity Identifier Code']"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="./datas[@name='Entity Type Qualifier']/@name"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./datas[@name='Entity Type Qualifier']"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="./datas[@name='Name Last or Organization Name']/@name"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./datas[@name='Name Last or Organization Name']"/>
        </li>
   </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

This will give you the following output:

```
<ul xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <li>Hierarchical Structure Code-0022</li>
  <li>Transaction Set Purpose Code-13</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Entity Identifier Code Entity Identifier Code-PR</li>
    <li>Entity Type Qualifier-2</li>
    <li>Name Last or Organization Name-UNITED</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Entity Identifier Code Entity Identifier Code-FA</li>
    <li>Entity Type Qualifier-</li>
    <li>Name Last or Organization Name-SWXRAY</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive variant. It uses `<ol>` instead of `<ul>` for numbering.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Elements</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    <xsl:text>ol { list-style-type: decimal; }</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>ol ol { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>ol ol ol { list-style-type: upper-roman; }</xsl:text>
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <ol>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/body/*"/>
                </ol>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="elements">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@description"/>
            <xsl:if test="datas">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="datas"/>
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="elements">
                <ol>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="elements"/>
                </ol>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datas">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datas[compositedatas]">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="compositedatas"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="compositedatas">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

1. Beginning of Hierarchical Transaction

   - Hierarchical Structure Code-0022
   - Transaction Set Purpose Code-13
   - Reference Identification-199
   - Date-20111219
   - Time-010720
   - Transaction Type Code-
2. Information Source Level

   1. Information Source Name

      - Entity Identifier Code-PR
      - Entity Type Qualifier-2
      - Name Last or Organization Name-UNITED
      - Name First-
      - Name Middle-
      - Name Prefix-
      - Name Suffix-
      - Identification Code Qualifier-PI
      - Identification Code-
      - Entity Relationship Code-
      - Entity Identifier Code-
3. Information Receiver Level

   1. Information Receiver Name

      - Entity Identifier Code-FA
      - Entity Type Qualifier-
      - Name Last or Organization Name-SWXRAY
      - Name First-
      - Name Middle-
      - Name Prefix-
      - Name Suffix-
      - Identification Code Qualifier-XX
      - Identification Code-1467524231
      - Entity Relationship Code-
      - Entity Identifier Code-

      1. Information Receiver Additional Identification

         - Reference Identification Qualifier-
         - Reference Identification-
         - Description-
         - REFERENCE IDENTIFIER-
      2. Information Receiver Address

         - Address Information-
         - Address Information-

      ...

*The inner numbered lists have different formats, but this can't be represented on SO*

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Elements</title>
    <style type="text/css">ol { list-style-type: decimal; }ol ol { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }ol ol ol { list-style-type: upper-roman; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>Beginning of Hierarchical Transaction<ul>
          <li>Hierarchical Structure Code-0022</li>
          <li>Transaction Set Purpose Code-13</li>
          <li>Reference Identification-199</li>
          <li>Date-20111219</li>
          <li>Time-010720</li>
          <li>Transaction Type Code-</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Information Source Level<ol>
          <li>Information Source Name<ul>
              <li>Entity Identifier Code-PR</li>
              <li>Entity Type Qualifier-2</li>
              <li>Name Last or Organization Name-UNITED</li>
              <li>Name First-</li>
              <li>Name Middle-</li>
              <li>Name Prefix-</li>
              <li>Name Suffix-</li>
              <li>Identification Code Qualifier-PI</li>
              <li>Identification Code-</li>
              <li>Entity Relationship Code-</li>
              <li>Entity Identifier Code-</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Information Receiver Level<ol>
          <li>Information Receiver Name<ul>
              <li>Entity Identifier Code-FA</li>
              <li>Entity Type Qualifier-</li>
              <li>Name Last or Organization Name-SWXRAY</li>
              <li>Name First-</li>
              <li>Name Middle-</li>
              <li>Name Prefix-</li>
              <li>Name Suffix-</li>
              <li>Identification Code Qualifier-XX</li>
              <li>Identification Code-1467524231</li>
              <li>Entity Relationship Code-</li>
              <li>Entity Identifier Code-</li>
            </ul>
            <ol>
              <li>Information Receiver Additional Identification<ul>
                  <li>Reference Identification Qualifier-</li>
                  <li>Reference Identification-</li>
                  <li>Description-</li>
                  <li>REFERENCE IDENTIFIER-</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Information Receiver Address<ul>
                  <li>Address Information-</li>
                  <li>Address Information-</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ol>
            ...
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```